# How to overwrite/cancel previous promise called one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, cancellation

I have jQuery code that respond to user keyboard press and I'm checking if element is in view. The plugin return promise if user press the key very fast or hold it (right now it's too fast for my code) it create promise in kind of loop. I want to cancel previous promise before I call new one.

I came up with this code that ignores previous promise:

```
var scroll_callback_counter = 0;
function move_cursor_visible() {
    var cursor = self.find('.cursor');
    var i = scroll_callback_counter++;
    return cursor.is_fully_in_viewport(self).then(function(visible) {
        if (i === scroll_callback_counter && !visible) {
            var offset = cursor.offset();
            var container_offset = self.offset();
            self.scrollTop(offset.top - container_offset.top - 5);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a better way? It works but I don't know if this is correct way to create code that cancel/ignore promise callback.

EDIT:

Here is `is_fully_in_viewport` function:

```
function jquery_resolve(value) {
    var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
    defer.resolve(value);
    return defer.promise();
}
$.fn.is_fully_in_viewport = (function() {
    function is_visible(node, container) {
        var box = node.getBoundingClientRect();
        var viewport = container[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = box.top - viewport.top;
        var bottom = box.bottom - viewport.top;
        var height = container.height();
        return bottom > 0 && top <= height;
    }
    if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
        return function(container) {
            var node = this[0];
            var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
            var item_observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
                defer.resolve(entries[0].isIntersecting);
                item_observer.unobserve(node);
            }, {
                root: container[0]
            });
            item_observer.observe(node);
            return defer.promise();
        };
    } else {
        return function(container) {
            return jquery_resolve(is_visible(this[0], container));
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Preventing the callback from running by checking whether it is the current one seems like the best thing you can do. If you actually wanted to cancel the work that your plugin is doing, that depends very much on what it actually is doing and why it uses promises at all - can you please post/link the `is_fully_in_viewport` function?

Comment: @Bergi `is_fully_in_viewport` need to return a promise because it use Intersection Observer to check if element is in view.

Comment: I guess in that case I'd completely drop the promise stuff. Pass a callback into `is_full_in_viewport`, and have only a single `IntersectionObserver` instance per jQuery element.

Answer (score 0):

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after
>   wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced
>   function was invoked.

You can use [**debounce**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) method of loadash,

```
_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

> The debounced function comes with a cancel method to cancel delayed
>   func invocations and a flush method to immediately invoke them

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. Completely forget about this function maybe it will work for my case.

Comment: Debouncing only works if `is_fully_in_viewport` is guaranteed to run in a fixed amount of time.